# Solution to automate setting MS file formats to open in LibreOffice

Tags: finder, applescript, libreoffice

Does anyone have a solution to swiftly set the default application across MS format documents to be LibreOffice for a largish number of users. To set out the problem:

1. Fifteen users have installed LibreOffice
2. We have many shared files on NextCloud in MS formats
3. All MS formats (doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx) continue to open in Pages and other apps
4. These can be set to open in LibreOffice manually, via the finder, one by one
5. It would be easier if a script could associate all the MS formats with LibreOffice

Does anyone know of a method to do this? Is there a .plist file or files that could be edited and bulk replaced? Has someone written a script to do something similar that could be edited or repurposed?

In research and the comments here, a PreferencePane, [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps/releases) is suggested. This speeds the process of changing the formats up, as the file formats don't have to be accessed from the finder, but it is still quite slow to change the app associated with all eight or twelve file formats.

Answer (score 2):

Command line tool [Duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti) can be used to change which application opens which extension, thus it is easy to supply users with installation details plus a command or commands to run to make these changes.